# jBPM5 configuring email service task

Tags: eclipse, jbpm, bpmn

I want to send an e-mail in my process. There is a service task node, which is called "E-mail", but I'm not sure how to configure to make it work.
Could you please provide me an example or describe a simple way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

do you have an accessible email server running? First you need to solve that.. once you get that up and running we can help you to configure the email work item :)
Cheers